# Sitio Web Engañoso: ¿Como eliminar definitivamente el problema en Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

tengo un problema con una web que estoy haciendo.
El navegador la marcaba como engañosa. Usando Google Search Console, me indicaba que rutas eran el problema. Borré esos directorios (se habian generado webs para robar datos de tarjetas de crédito) y despues de 2 días, Google ya había quitado el mensaje de Web Engañosa.

Pense que el problema estaba solucionado, pero despues de 2 días volvió a surgir el problema, vuelvo a entrar a Google Search Console y eran los mismos archivos que ya habia borrado antes, con la diferencia de que esta vez se robaban datos de otra entidad bancaria.

Borré todo el FTP e hice una instalación limpia de WordPress, 
cambié la contraseña del Cpanel, 
instalé el plugin WordFence y lo he puesto a analizar, 
también me di cuenta que la versión de PHP que usaba mi Cpanel era 5.4 y lo puse en 7.1.

¿Qué más debería hacer?
Mi idea era probar una a una las cosas que he comentado arriba, para asi descubrir cual es el error, pero necesito tenerla cuanto antes online, y por eso he hecho todos los cambios a la vez y he mandado la revisión de Google Search Console de nuevo.

Hay algo más que me recomienden?
Las páginas engañosas que me detecta Google Search Console se instalan en:
**/wp-admin/js/www/a.php** y **/wp-admin/js/www/ro/**

muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

Por como detallas la situación: Cambiarte de hosting es la solución más factible.

Sucede que si los hackers han accedido al servidor y tiene acceso root o de algún usuario del tipo de administrador, tienen a su merced los archivos.

Hace años me sucedió algo muy parecido, el problema fue que estaba deshabilitado el firewall tanto a nivel de aplicación como a nivel de servidor. Actualizar el servidor, activar ambos firewalls, actualizar los wordpress, eliminar los archivos infectados, verificar si existen "web shells" y proceder a

1. Capturarlas para estudiarlas.
2. Eliminarlas del servidor.

Revisa este post: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/28378/822